# postman-'sending request error' for nodejs and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am a new to nodejs and postman, trying to run my CRUD operations and facing a problem where postman say's sending request forever, don't know what exactly is wrong, database got connected but seems api's are not valid.

[postman endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1teuR.png)

here's my code

```
const express=require('express');
const bodyParser=require('body-parser');
const mongoose=require('mongoose');



 const locRoute=require("./routes/location");



mongoose.set('strictQuery', true)
const app=express();
const PORT=7400;


 const MONGO_URI="mongodb://localhost:27017/myrough";


mongoose.connect(MONGO_URI,()=>{
    console.log('connected to db');
},e=>console.log("Error",e));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/location', locRoute);    
app.get('/',(req,res)=>res.send('working'))


app.listen(PORT,()=>{
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
})
```

app.get is working but app.use doesnot work

here's the location route:-

```
const express=require('express');
const locationController=require('../Controllers/location')

const routes=express.Router();
console.log('menu')
routes.get('/',locationController.getLocations);

module.exports=routes;
```

location controller:-

```
const locations=require('../Models/location');


exports.getLocations=(req,res)=>{
    locations.find().then(result=>{
        res.status(200).json({
            message:"locations successfully fetched from DB",
            data:result
            
            
        })
        
    }).catch(error=>{
        res.status(500).json({
            message:"locations not found",
            error:error
        })
    });
}
```

location model:-

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');

const locationSchema= mongoose.Schema({
    
name:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    
city_id:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    location_id:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    
country_name:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    }
});

module.exports=mongoose.model("Locations",locationSchema,"locations");
```

mongodb data:-

```
{
  "_id": "1",
  "name": "ShalimarBhagh, Delhi",
  "city_id": "1",
  "location_id": "1",
  "country_name": "India"
},
{
  "_id": "2",
  "name": "Janpat, Delhi",
  "city_id": "1",
  "location_id": "2",
  "country_name": "India"
}
```

Comment: Can you add an image of how you are calling the endpoint from Postman?

Comment: yes, posted at the top of the code.....

Answer (score 0):

Try this should fix your issue...

In Location Model file

```js
const Location = mongoose.model("Locations", locationSchema);
module.exports= { Location };
```

In Location controller file

```js
const { Location } = require('../Models/location');
const getLocations = (req, res) => {
    Location.find().exec((err, locationList) => {
        if(err) { 
            res.status(500).json({
                message:"locations not found",
                error:err
           });
       }
       res.status(200).json({
            message:"locations successfully fetched from DB",
            data:locationList  
        });
    });

}

module.exports = { getLocations }
```

In Location route file

```js
const { getLocations } = require('../Controllers/location');
routes.get('/', getLocations);
```